# boost spirit and boost any - unexpected result

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-any

I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename Iterator>
struct parser : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, boost::any, boost::spirit::qi::ascii::space_type>
{
  parser() : parser::base_type(start)
  {
    start %= boost::spirit::qi::int_;
  }

  boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, boost::any, boost::spirit::qi::ascii::space_type> start;
};

int main()
{
  const std::string input_data("1");

  boost::any var;
  auto itr = input_data.begin();
  auto end = input_data.end();
  parser<decltype(itr)> g;
  bool res = boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(itr, end, g, boost::spirit::ascii::space, var);
  if (res && itr == end)
  {
    std::cout << "Parsing succeeded \n";
    try
    {
      std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>(var) << '\n';
    }
    catch (const boost::bad_any_cast& ex)
    {
      std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Parsing failed \n";
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
Parsing succeeded
boost::bad_any_cast: failed conversion using boost::any_cast
```

I think that cast should work fine in such case. Am i wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your any!

```
boost::any var = 0;
```

Spirit **binds** the attribute value by reference, so it will cast to `int&` before invoking the `qi::int_` parser.

On a side note, using `boost::any` with Spirit seems like misguided plan. I can't see why you'd diverge from statically known types and e.g. Variant. But I'll leave that up to you :)

**P.S.** Oh, and you forgot some more parentheses [like here :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21633154/85371). See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c862d905bc85671e)** now

Comment: Thanks a lot! btw can you help me with the following problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647277/boost-spirit-boost-any-and-quoted-string-compile-time-error

Comment: You're "paying the complexity prize" - Spirit favours strongly typed attributes. I expect you'd run into many more issues. Of course, I can't know, but it's my gut feeling :(